# Facebook server-side authentication: I cannot display an OAuth dialog as a popup instead as a page 

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth, dialog, popup

I'm using server side Facebook authentication. So first, the application redirects the client to `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?...` [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator), and in this URL there is, as a parameter, the string "display=popup", but when the application redirects the client the dialog is displayed as page, so no window is opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server side can only redirect to a [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator); it cannot tell the client in which window to open/display the URL.

Facebook's client-side authentication takes care of showing the OAuth dialog in a popup window. If you have to use server-side authentication, you'll need to open the URL in a popup yourself:

```
window.open('URL_THAT_REDIRECTS_TO_OAUTH_DIALOG', ...)
```

but then you'll also need to set up the window dimensions (width/height) yourself (by specifying them in `window.open()`).

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is correct. Though remember to use '_blank' to have an actual popup:

```
window.open('/fblogin', '_blank','location=yes, scrollbars=yes, width=640, height=359', true);
```

These are also the sizes for the current OAuth login window.